# Border radius Swift Ios

Tags: ios, swift2

Como puedo poner un border radius a una `UIView` en `swift`, pero solo en la parte de arriba, abajo tiene que ser recto

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
caja!.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
```

pero me muestra el border en toda la caja

Alguna solucion??

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple es la siguiente:

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: caja.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(7.5, 7.5))

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = caja.bounds
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath
caja.layer.mask = maskLayer
```